# What does the at symbol (@) do in ES6 javascript? (ECMAScript 2015)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-next

I'm looking at some ES6 code and I don't understand what the @ symbol does when it is placed in front of a variable. The closest thing I could find has something to do with private fields?

Code I was looking at from the [redux library](https://github.com/gaearon/redux/blob/master/examples/counter/containers/CounterApp.js#L7):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'redux/react';
import Counter from '../components/Counter';
import * as CounterActions from '../actions/CounterActions';

@connect(state => ({
  counter: state.counter
}))
export default class CounterApp extends Component {
  render() {
    const { counter, dispatch } = this.props;
    return (
      <Counter counter={counter}
               {...bindActionCreators(CounterActions, dispatch)} />
    );
  }
}
```

Here is a blog post I found on the topic: https://github.com/zenparsing/es-private-fields

In this blog post all the examples are in the context of a class - what does it mean when the symbol is used within a module?

Comment: Those are called annotations.

Comment: Those are not ES6, but some experimental transpiler thing. The article you linked is a *proposal* for *ES7*.

Comment: Can you add an `@` to the title so that this shows up in searches for `@ javascript`?

Comment: @adc17 did that. Good idea.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It's a *decorator*. It's a **proposal** to be added to ECMAScript. There are multiple ES6 and ES5 equivalent examples on: [javascript-decorators](https://github.com/wycats/javascript-decorators).

> Decorators dynamically alter the functionality of a function, method, or class without having to directly use subclasses or change the source code of the function being decorated.

They are commonly used to control access, registration, annotation.

Answer (score 91):

I found the accepted answer was not enough to help me sort this out, so I'm adding a little more detail to help others who find this.

The problem is that it's unclear exactly *what* is the decorator. The decorator in the example given is not just the `@` symbol, it's the `@connect` function. Simply put, the `@connect` function is **decorating** the `CounterApp` class.

And what is it doing in this case? It's *connecting* the `state.counter` value to the props of the class. Remember that in redux the `connect` function takes two arguments: `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`. In this example, it's taking only one argument - `mapStateToProps`.

I haven't investigated this too much, but this appears to be a way to encapsulate your state-to-props and dispatch-to-props mappings so they accompany your components rather than being located in a different file.

Comment: `@connect` indeed does that, but, speaking generally,   
But I'd say *WiTH DECORATOR WE JUST ADD FUNCTION ON-THE-FLY *

I saw `@injectIntl()` (for react-intl),`@reduxForm` (for redux-form) and many other used like this.

Answer (score 20):

### What is `@myDecorator()`?

The `@` symbol in javascript stands for a decorator. Decorators are not present in `ES6` so the in code you are working with the decorator is probably transpiled to an version of javascript which can be run in any browser.

### What is a decorator?

A decorator extends (i.e. decorates) an object’s behavior dynamically. The ability to add new behavior at runtime is accomplished by a Decorator object which ‘wraps itself’ around the original object. A decorator is not just a concept in javascript. It is a **design pattern** used in all object oriented programming languages. Here is a definition from wikipedia:

> In object-oriented programming, the **decorator pattern** is a **design
>   pattern** that allows behavior to be added to an individual object,
>   dynamically, without affecting the behavior of other objects from the
>   same class. The decorator pattern is often useful for adhering to the
>   Single Responsibility Principle, as it allows functionality to be
>   divided between classes with unique areas of concern

### Why use a decorator?

The functionality of an object can be modified at runtime when using a decorator. For example, in your code you simply imported the decorator and added it to your `CounterApp` class. Now your  `CounterApp` has dynamically added functionality **Without you knowing the implementation details.**

### Example:

```
// decorator lights is a function which receives the class as an argument
let lights = function(tree) {
  // The behaviour of the class is modified here
  tree.treeLights = 'Christmas lights'
}

@lights  // the decorator is applied here
class ChristmasTree {}

console.log(ChristmasTree.treeLights);  // logs Christmas lights
```

Comment: So what's the difference between `connect(...)` and `@connect(...)`?