# My javascript snippet returns "illegal characters"

Tags: javascript, node.js, decorator

I'm trying to achieve a snippet corresponding to an example found in [this book](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/practical-es6/9781492067184/Text/Section0010.html). Here my Javascript snippet: 
"use strict"

```
function readObject(target, name, descriptor) {
    return console.log("reading object...: ", target, name, descriptor)
}


class Example {
  a() {}
  @readObject
  b() {}
}

const e = new Example();
e.a = 1;
e.b = 2;
```

My console returns:

> line 12 _ SyntaxError: illegal character

I have also tried:

```
function readonly(target, name, descriptor) {
  descriptor.writable = false;
  return descriptor;
}


class Example {
  a() {}
  @readonly
  b() {}
}

const e = new Example();
e.a = 1;
e.b = 2;
```

the later trial fails too.

It seems to me I have defined `readObject`.

Maybe I have forgot an another element?

Any hint would be great,
thanks.

Comment: Have you tried removing the @readObject string? This is not valid JS

Comment: it may be because you forgot to add a semicolon

Comment: @Loupax *cough* https://stackoverflow.com/q/43447082/476

Comment: @Loupax see also: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html

Comment: seems issue is with your decorator not being properly defined

Comment: From the above link: *"Decorators use the form @expression, where expression must evaluate to a function that will be called at runtime with information about the decorated declaration"* `readObject()` does not evaluate to a function.

Comment: @deceze ok, wow, I just looked away for a second and we now have decorators? Madness!

Comment: @Loupax -- I don't think we can use decorators yet in Node, but they're in Typescript.

Comment: @Webwoman It's somewhat unclear, what you are trying to achieve. Should your decorator always be called, when you access the `b` property of your `Example` class?

Comment: thanks for comments, I have also tried with objects following the book's example, seems it fails. I'm just trying to reproduce a book example to ensure I'm following the book pace and understanding the  concept illustrated inside

Answer (score 0):

Seems it was a transpiler probem, the code works better using appropriated transpiler, in jsfiddle for example:

https://jsfiddle.net/wergsdba/1/

```js
console.log("go on the link to appreciate the code using ES7")
```

Comment: Please check my answer below. Could you test this out and give me some feedback?

Comment: yes of course, I have just tested it and yep, we can also use decorators on class properties, your code works too with ES7

Answer (score -1):

I guess the real error message would be something like: "Leading decorators must be attached to a class declaration".

The decorator has to be before the class declaration, not inside.

**EDIT**
You also can use decorators on class properties.
I guess the code should look something like this:

```
class Example {
  @readObject
  a = {};
  constructor(){
    //...
  }
}
```