# How to allow '@' keyword in Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, interpreter, ecma

I'm trying to allow '@' functions in my application, what should I add or insert to allow JS to interpret it, just like "angular2 @Component".

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. Do you want to implement your own decorator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@` is used as a [decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31821084/what-does-the-at-symbol-do-in-es6-javascript-ecmascript-2015) in a new [proposed feature](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ikxIP5-RVYq6d_f8lAvf3pKC00W78ueyp-xIZ6q67uU/edit) for JavaScript. To use it you need to use a preprocessor like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/). *It is also available in typescript and widely used in Angular2.* Example:

```
function myDecorator(value) {
   return function(target) {
      target.myProperty = value;
   }
}

@myDecorator('myValue')
class MyClass { }
```

Decorators will not work by default on Babel, you can find information on enabling them [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/syntax-decorators/).

*Edit: Whether you consider `@myDecorator('myValue')` as `@` being part of the function name or not, I think we can all acknowledge that it would look this way to those new to the language.*

Related Links:

https://medium.com/google-developers/exploring-es7-decorators-76ecb65fb841
https://cabbageapps.com/fell-love-js-decorators/

Comment: ES6 did *not* introduce decorators. They are still just a [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators), but they are part of [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html)

Comment: _Please_ do not spread misinformation. Decorators are a proposal, they are not part of any specific version of the ECMAScript spec. Saying they are "ES6" is 100% a lie.

Comment: A lie is purposeful and malicious which this is not. From what I've read one can use decorators with babel and a later version of ES. If you have a more accurate answer please post it. @loganfsmyth

Comment: Fair, didn't mean to imply that it was purposeful, sorry. It's just frustrating because it's a common misconception and gets spread around here often. "ES6 (ES2015)" is a specific version of the spec that came out 2 years ago. If decorators were in there, you'd be able to use them in most JS environments by now without Babel. The fact that you need Babel to use a feature usually means it's a proposal and not in any ES* version, or only very recently got added to the official spec.

Comment: @loganfsmyth for ES2017 do you know if it is a standard feature or still a proposal?

Comment: The place to look is https://github.com/tc39/proposals. Decorators are a "stage 2" proposal following the process described in https://tc39.github.io/process-document/. Reaching stage 4 means they will be included in the next year-based spec version. ES2017 was released in June, at the earliest it would be ES2018 but even that is pretty optimistic.

Answer (score 1):

According to [a variable name validator](https://mothereff.in/js-variables) for *JavaScript*, *@* is a:

> invalid identifier according to ECMAScript 6 / Unicode 8.0.0

And so it is invalid for function names as well. See also: [What characters are valid for JavaScript variable names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/what-characters-are-valid-for-javascript-variable-names)
In *Angular* you actually use *TypeScript* and they make use of *@* as a decorator of a function, but it's not used in a function name.