# What does the symbol '@' mean in JavaScriptCore?

Tags: javascript, webkit, javascriptcore

I was reading JavaScriptCore' s source code and I stumbled upon this after a short while. The code sort of makes sense, but what happens exactly when '@' is used ?

```
[...]
if (@isArray(currentElement)) {
        constructor = currentElement.constructor;
        [...]
        if (@isArrayConstructor(constructor) && @Array !== constructor)
            constructor = @undefined;
        else if (@isObject(constructor)) {
            constructor = constructor.@speciesSymbol;
            if (constructor === null)
                constructor = @Array;
        }
    }
[...]
```

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14143123/does-the-symbol-have-special-meaning-in-javascript-coffeescript-or-jquery) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/what-characters-are-valid-for-javascript-variable-names/9337047#9337047) but they didn't help much ('@' is not a reserved character in Javascript)

Comment: Possibly related: [What does the at symbol (@) do in ES6 javascript? (ECMAScript 2015)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31821084/what-does-the-at-symbol-do-in-es6-javascript-ecmascript-2015)

Comment: The first link I posted was probably outdated, hence why I concluded it isn't a keyword. They may be indeed decorators. I can't find where they are defined inside the code base though

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer myself. As @p-s-w-g pointed out, those are decorators. The defintions for the ones I was looking for can be found in:
*webkit/Source/JavaScriptCore/runtime/ArrayConstructor.h*

```
inline bool isArray(ExecState* exec, JSValue argumentValue)
{
    if (!argumentValue.isObject())
        return false;

    JSObject* argument = jsCast<JSObject*>(argumentValue);
    if (argument->type() == ArrayType || argument->type() == DerivedArrayType)
        return true;

    if (argument->type() != ProxyObjectType)
        return false;
    return isArraySlow(exec, jsCast<ProxyObject*>(argument));
}
```